# Get data from specific column in excel using automation anywhere

Tags: automationanywhere

We need to fetch data from column in an excel sheet.
The problem is that order of column can change as e.g

[image]

Same file can be configured as :

[image]

So how do we fetch data from **Marks** column.

Have tried Start Loop control (Each row in Excel dataset Session)
But I don't see any control to loop through all the columns for row in current iteration (nested loop).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You actually do not need to use a number for the `Excel Column` system variable, you can use the column name directly (and without quotes) provided you have selected that the Excel dataset contains headers.

[image]